# how to disable a button with a specific id in a for loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable a button with a specific id but it's not working

```
$('.likes-button').click(function(){
    var el= this;
    var button1 = $(el).attr('id');
    console.log(button1)
    $('#button1').attr("disabled",true);
});
```

```
<div class="col-4">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <a> <button class=" btn btn-warning btn-dark likes-button "  data-id="{{ product.id}}" id="button1-{{ forloop.counter }}"   > <span class="oi oi-thumb-up"></span> <strong class="string">{{product.stringlike}}</strong> <strong class="target" >{{product.votes_total_like}}</strong> </button></a>
    <a> <button class=" btn btn-warning btn-dark dislike-button"  data-id="{{ product.id}}" id="button2-{{ forloop.counter }}"   ><span class="oi oi-thumb-down"></span> <strong class="distring">{{product.stringdislike}}</strong> <strong class="distarget" >{{product.votes_total_dislike}}</strong></button></a>
</div>
```

the console.log display the clicked button id = `button1-1`

Comment: why is there a button in an anchor? That is not valid HTML.

Comment: Side note; `$(el).attr('id')` should just be `this.id` or `el.id`.  There's no benefit to wrapping an element in jQuery to get a property, when the property is already exposed on the Element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write `$('#'+button1).attr("disabled",true);` instead of `$('#button1').attr("disabled",true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.likes-button').click( ()=> {
    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Comment: So think about this for just a second.  You're taking the `e.target`, which is a reference to an element, and then you're using its id to look it up.  To look up an element, you already have a reference to.

Comment: i don't understand  e.target.id ??

Comment: `e.target` is the Element that the event originated from.

Comment: Please include some explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The id in the button is not the same

```
id="button1-{{ forloop.counter }}"
```

You could try `$('[id^="button1"]').attr("disabled", true);` in your jquery selector, but your function doesn't really make much sense. If you already have a unique class in likes-button, you could just do

```
$('.likes-button').click(function() {
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

or just

```
$('.likes-button').click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Without jQuery

```
document.querySelector(".likes-button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.target.setAttribute("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: great, but what if i have two button like and dislike , how can i access the second button dislike-button  from the first button likes-button ??

Comment: If you want to access the dislike button when you click on the like button you can query it inside the event listener `$('.likes-button').click(function() { console.log($('.dislike-button')) });`

Comment: the problem is  i have 2 post every post have like and dislike button , if i do as you say then i will select two button instead of one , i know i have to use the button id but how ?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use the `sibling()` jQuery function if you don't want to select other `.dislike-button`s. `$('.likes-button').click(function(e) { $(e.target).siblings('.dislike-button') })` will select only the `.dislike-button` that is a sibling of the `.like-button` you clicked.

Comment: but its return the likes button, not the dislike button ??

Comment: Not sure I understand. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4ru3zxt/). Is this not what you need?

Comment: I want something similar to this https://jsfiddle.net/e1cpt96n/17/ , but its not working

Comment: Part of that code has bugs, the sibling function accepts selectors, you're passing `dislike-button` without the `.`. You're also not querying the right  `likes-button` class in some of your definitions. What you seem to want is disable one of the two buttons if either one is clicked, right? If so, check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nthpaz0/).

Comment: that's awesome , one more question , what if i have ajax request for both buttons like and dislike how would it be ?

Comment: Like you normally would, just do de ajax call inside of the listener. If you want to disable the other button when the ajax is successful, do it inside the callback, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7sj2v4e/).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this way

```
 $('.likes-button').click(function(){
            var button1 = "#"+ $(this).attr('id');
            $($button1).prop('disabled',true).css('opacity',0.5);
 });
```